# Which gem provides the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

The `rails` gem has dependencies upon several other gems. Which gem provides the Rails console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of the [railties gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/railties/versions/4.2.4).

The file it runs is `$YOUR_GEM_INSTALL_PATH/railties-$VERSION/lib/rails/commands/console.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Many different versions of rails

But looking back to rails 3.x https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/3.2.9

The `rails` console bin is in `railties` gem

`./railties-3.2.9/bin/rails`